# Add times smarty

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I have an array I am looping in smarty with duration times like 3:20 and for example 1:45:32 , need to add all times and get a final time for example 1:48:52 , if there is simple way in smarty to do this ?

Comment: Can you post some of your code so we can see what you're fully talking about?

Comment: There isnt any code yet, I am just trying to imagine how to do that, normally on php I do convert to seconds, do the operations and then put back on time format but will need to do this in smarty so want to know if there is a simple way to add duration times in smarty

Answer (score 1):

No, Smarty doesn't have any function to do that. What you can do, however, is create your own smarty modifier to add this functionality. Another option would be doing the calculation in php and send the result to smarty as another variable.